# Error trying to connect R to Googlesheet using package googlesheets4: Can't get Google credentials

Tags: r, googlesheets4

I've a problem while trying to connect R with Googlesheet (package googlesheets4):

> Error:Can't get Google credentials. Are you running googlesheets4 in a
> non-interactive session? Consider: *`gs4_deauth()` to prevent the
> attempt to get credentials. * Call `gs4_auth()` directly with all
> necessary specifics. See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for
> more details:
> https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html

My R version is 4.0.3, the code was running properly when I've had version 3.5.3

Comment: VPN access was blocked, swapping to a different IP did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved the same error message problem that I was seeing from `googlesheets4` and `googledrive` with the help of [this advice](https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/troubleshooting.html) from the `gargle`package's troubleshooting page.

Package `gargle` is doing the behind the scenes work with G**gle's API and it seems that the problem is packages that `gargle` calls that might need to be updated for R versions >4.0.

To see if that is your case, change the `gargle_verbosity` argument from the default "info" to "debug" to see all the different attempts that `gargle` uses to provoke the authorisation process.

```
op <- options(gargle_verbosity = "debug")
```

For me, by re-running `gs4_auth()` or any similar function, I saw that the version of the `curl` package predated R version 4.0 and needed to be reinstalled.

After reinstalling `curl`, the browser log-in step worked but the function still could not generate / store a token because `openssl` also needed to be reinstalled for R versions >4.0.

Then I ran

```
options(op)
```

when I tired of `gargle`'s verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too.
I did not find any issues at all with the `Gargle` package, sorry.
Instead, what worked for me and should work for you was throwing the following into the console:

`devtools::install_github("tidyverse/googlesheets4")`

(it might work just fine with the "regular" version, but I did not get to test it, as many people complained online about versions being the potential issue... so I just went directly for the latest available one...)

```
library(googlesheets4)  
gs4_auth()
```

the console responds with:

> Waiting for authentication in browser...
> Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
> Authentication complete.

You actually don't get to see the message at first, because the command opens up immediately your browser (`google chrome` in my case) and you are asked to grant access to your `Google drive`: simply click the unticked box and then the page changes again and you see a message "authentification granted, close this page to get back to `R`"...
Now in `R`, you see the message above, and everything now works as expected! :-)