# gs4_auth() can't get Google credentials in an interactive session

Tags: r, tidyverse, googlesheets4

After updating to R 4.2.1, I'm getting the following error when running a sheet_write() command

> Error in `gs4_auth()`:
>
> ! Can't get Google credentials.
>
> ℹ Are you running googlesheets4 in a non-interactive session?
>
> Consider:
>
> • Call `gs4_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
>
> • Call `gs4_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
>
> ℹ See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
>
> ℹ https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html

Same error message appears when I run `gs4_auth(email = "Person@email.com")`

I'm not attempting to include this code in a .rmd - I'm just trying to push a df to Google Sheets and I'm getting this error.

I've fresh installed r and rstudio. The only other change that I've recently done is following the direction on this mplus.R source (https://www.statmodel.com/mplus-R/Mplus%20R%20tutorial.pdf) but I don't believe it would result in this error.

I'm completely perplexed why this is happening and any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I decided to post the question after hours of debating... I figured it out with the help of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64909304/error-trying-to-connect-r-to-googlesheet-using-package-googlesheets4-cant-get). Essentially 'openssl' wouldn't install on my machine if I compiled it, but it did if I didn't compile it.